# Getting javascript events to an object that's covered up

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-ui

I'm trying to build a jquery app where I have a fixed image and a second draggable image.  I need the fixed image to display z-index on top of the moveable image -- the fixed image is a picture with an alpha cut-out hole for a face like you might find at an amusement park.  The problem is that as soon as the moveable (face) image is overlapping with the fixed image, click and drag events get captured by the fixed image which is on top and don't get to the moveable image.  So it's no longer moveable.  Here's my code...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="fixed" style="position:relative; z-index: 2">
    <img src="background.png">
</div>

<div id="face" style="position:relative; z-index: 1">
    <img src="face.png">
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#face").draggable();
    });
</script>
```

How can I get the face object to be draggable when it's behind the fixed background?  Can I manually fire the mouse events on the object underneath?  If so, how do I invoke them so the jquery-ui draggable() works properly?  Can I somehow get the fixed image just not to capture events?  Or do I need to write my own draggable mechanism by hand?

Comment: I think you'll have to find a way to relay the event information onto the jQuery `draggable()` function handler set on `#face`. The information you need should be found here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i found a pretty simple solution for you. Basically you can relay the event only when certain conditions are met (eg #face is under the #fixed). [Check out this fiddle for example](http://jsfiddle.net/MeuRf/5/).

A quick look at the even data revealed that draggable only binds mousedown, so that seems to be the only event you will need to relay.

```
$('#face').draggable();

$('#fixed').bind('mousedown', function(e){
    // TODO: IF #face is under #fixed AND mouse is over #face THEN
   $('#face').trigger(e); // trigger the event on face
});
```

Comment: Awesome.  This is what I needed to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be better off creating some sort of "drag handle" to the element underneath, which would always be visible (at least while dragging is enabled). That, or a separate UI control separated from the images which would act as a "joystick" for the draggable image, so that you could move the image without having to manually drag/drop the image itself.

Think about it: lets say they drag the item underneath the top item, then drop it; how are they to pick it up again? If this is setup like you explained (*a cut-out hole for a face like you might find at an amusement park*), then the user would not be able to visibly see the element underneath, and as such, it would be impossible for them to interact with that element using the mouse.

Comment: Great suggestion.  I'll probably do this too.